# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Memory Allocation Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, memory-management

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance that is running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise server that has been allocated 128GB of memory.  However, it maxes out at 70GB.  Can anyone tell me how I can allow the SQL server to utilize the majority of its memory??  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. This is more server configuration. Try the DBA and/or  serverfault sites.

Answer (score 0):

Question moved to Database Administrators forum.